# undefined reference to protected static member. How do I solve it?

Tags: c++, class, g++, linker-errors

In robots.hpp I have a `class`, `robots`. I want each robot to have a pointer to another robot, the one that was declared last. I also want each to have a unique id. For this I have a variable that counts the number of robots.

It seems that I can't initialise my static variables in the class definition. I looked up how to solve that, and found something recommending initialising them in robots.cpp. However, that gives me an error saying that they are protected, and so I can't do that. So now I have a function that is called by the constructor only once, at the beginning.

**However**, that is giving me an error saying that I can't do that, because they haven't been defined yet.

The class definition in robots.hpp:

```
class robot
{
    public:
        ///initialiser.
        robot();
        [...]
        ///initialises all robots
        void initrobots();
        ///id of robot
        const uint_least8_t id=NumOfRobots++;
        static bool hasBeenInitialised;
    protected:
        ///number of robots.
        static uint_least8_t NumOfRobots;
        ///pointer to the next robot that needs pointing to.
        static robot* poiRobot;
        [...]
        ///pointer to next robot
        robot* nextRobot;
};
```

robots.cpp:

```
bool robot::hasBeenInitialised=false;

void robot::initrobots(){
    poiRobot=NULL;
    NumOfRobots=0;
}
robot::robot(){
    if(!hasBeenInitialised){
        initrobots();
        hasBeenInitialised=true;
    }
[...]
}
```

The code that generates this error is this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

class robot
{
    public:
        ///initialiser.
        robot();
        //[...]
        ///initialises all robots
        void initrobots();
        ///id of robot
        const uint_least8_t id=NumOfRobots++;
        static bool hasBeenInitialised;
    protected:
        ///number of robots.
        static uint_least8_t NumOfRobots;
        ///pointer to the next robot that needs pointing to.
        static robot* poiRobot;
        //[...]
        ///pointer to next robot
        robot* nextRobot;
};

bool robot::hasBeenInitialised=false;

void robot::initrobots(){
    poiRobot=NULL;
    NumOfRobots=0;
}
robot::robot(){
    if(!hasBeenInitialised){
        initrobots();
        hasBeenInitialised=true;
    }
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it it doesn't complain, but it does complain if I build it (using geany to do the things separately, c++11 standard(otherwise cstdint complains))

I would like the code to make `poiRobot` a pointer to `null`, and `NumofRobots` equal to 0.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] where you show how you tried to initialize the member?

Comment: I just tried compiling `class Test { protected: static int x; }; int Test::x = 2;` in GCC and it works fine.

Comment: The protectedness shouldn't matter at all; `robot* robot::poiRobot;` should work just as well as the definition of `hasBeenInitialised`. If it doesn't, post the code that produces the error along with a copy of the error message (don't paraphrase, use Copy and Paste).

Comment: @molbdnilo I did cut and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get rid of `static bool hasBeenInitialised;` and `bool robot::hasBeenInitialised=false;` as well as your initialization function and just declare `uint_least8_t robot::NumOfRobots = 0;` and `robot* robot::poiRobot = nullptr` directly in your cpp file. This way they initialize themselves to 0 and null automatically. As mentioned in the comments this is valid, protected static variables should be able to be defined in the source file in this manner.

Edit: In regards to the code you posted in your edit, it looks like you are never defining robot::poiRobot and robot::NumRobots. Did you try the code I posted above?

Basically, each cpp file in your project must be compiled into a translation unit by the compiler. Then the linker comes through and takes all of the translation unit's and links them together. Any cpp file that sees your robot class will see that you've promised that those 2 variables exist somewhere, and therefore when you use them it will allow it (as far is it is concerned, they exist and are good to go). When the linker comes along it will see references to those variables and try to find which translation unit they were defined in so that it can do its job (link everything together). At this point, it won't see a definition in any translation unit, and that is why it gives you that error.

`uint_least8_t robot::NumOfRobots = 0;` and `robot* robot::poiRobot = nullptr` are the definitions you are looking for, and should go in your cpp file. If after using those you get another error about them being protected as you had hinted at earlier, post that code so we can see why that is happening.

Edit 2 in regards to "It seems that I can't initialise my static variables in the class definition.": When you put that definition in the header file, each cpp file that includes your header will define it's own version of that variable. When the linker goes to link everything it will see multiple definitions in different translation units for the same variable and that violates the "One Definition Rule" in C++ (ODR). That is why it will give you an error. It is correct to put it in robots.cpp so only 1 translation unit (robots.cpp in this case) will have the definition. Then you have to make sure that robots.cpp is being compiled in your project so that the translation unit is available for the linker... as you could mistakenly just include robots.h in your source files, but never tell the compiler to compile robots.cpp.

Comment: The OP has said they did this but got an error.  We need to OP to provide a mcve including the error before we know what is really going on.

Comment: @MarkGardner updated in regards to your edit

Comment: I need them to be static, and non-constant. And I do tell it to compile robots.cpp.

Comment: @MarkGardner what I shared is static, and non-constant. It simply initializes NumOfRobots to 0 and poiRobot to NULL at the beginning of the programs runtime, but you can modify them after that. They are also static, therefore shared between objects of robot.

Comment: I don't see anything.

Comment: Before the creation of hasBeenIntiialised, there were two variables. and they complained when they were initialised outside, that they are protected.

Comment: strangely this works now. I wonder what I did wrong.

Comment: @MarkGardner Glad to hear it worked. Usually just a small typo somewhere, that gets me all the time  :)